# Changing the temp directory location on device

Tags: c#, android, adb, madbee

I am using Managed-ADB or Madbee library to access adb in C#. I am properly getting all the devices and can access the packages and other info from the device. However when I try to install any apk using device.installPackage() method, it returns FileNotFoundException. After checking the exception message, I got to know that it's accessing `sdcard/tmp` location on device, which i snot accessible, since my device doesn't have a sdcard. I am trying to find a way to change the default location, but with no success.

I suppose, It's taking that location from `TEMP_DIRECTORY_FOR_INSTALL` constant in Device class. I don't think there's any way to change it's value. Is there any way I can change the default temp directory to something accessible such as `data/local/temp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to download the source, change the value of constant `TEMP_DIRECTORY_FOR_INSTALL` and then recompile it. I don't think there was any other way. I chose `/mnt/sdcard/tmp` as location, which is working fine on all of my devices.

Comment: can you try /storage/sdcard0/tmp/ and see if that works as well?